# ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord: Diff is marked as readonly on destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rake task that looks like this:

```
desc "Cleanup Snippets with Empty Diffs"

task cleanup_snippets_with_empty_diffs: :environment do
  Snippet.includes(:diffs).where(diffs: { body: "<div class=\"diff\"></div>"}).destroy_all
end
```

Yet when I run it, I get this:

```
$ rake cleanup_snippets_with_empty_diffs
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord: Diff is marked as readonly
```

What could be the cause of this?

**Edit 1**

Note that my `Snippet.rb` model looks like this:

```
class Snippet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :diffs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And `Diff.rb` like this:

```
class Diff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :snippet
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `includes`, Rails will determine whether to use multiple queries (using [`preload`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-preload)) or a single left outer join query (using [`eager_load`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-eager_load)). In your case, because your where clause is on the association, Rails will use `eager_load` and therefore a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Also note that associations loaded via a join are marked as `readonly` and is the cause of the error you're receiving. The solution is to switch `includes` to `left_joins` and set `readonly(false)` prior to calling `destroy_all`.

```
Snippet.left_joins(:diffs).readonly(false).where(diffs: { body: "<div class=\"diff\"></div>"}).destroy_all
```

**NOTE**

I originally thought you could do

```
Snippet.includes(:diffs).readonly(false).where(diffs: { body: "<div class=\"diff\"></div>"}).destroy_all
```

but this doesn't work for some reason (and don't have enough time to investigate atm). In any case, since using `includes` would result in a LEFT OUTER JOIN anyways, you can use the above solution to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Remember I am using `includes`, not `joins`.

Comment: Sorry by `joins` I meant *a join* and not necessarily the `joins` method. Please see my updated answer for further explanation and a possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Life saver!